# How can I set a global variable based on the json response in Postman

Tags: json, postman

I have a situation where I need to check every array within json respone and based on the search set a global variable.

Here is my example:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "de240551-2dcd-4eb0-b8d1-7d18f4a68bcf",
      "title": "Number 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "319e87ab-2bfe-4e7d-a67a-00e462a4fcc6",
      "title": "Number 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "66a890c8-c043-4721-b6ae-874e8d2fcd95",
      "title": "Number 3"
    }
  ],
}
```

I need to set a variable but for a specific array.
In my example, I need to search for a "title": "Number 2" and only then set a global variable for id in this array.

In other words, I need to set a global variable for "id": "319e87ab-2bfe-4e7d-a67a-00e462a4fcc6" if "title": "Number 2".

Is there a way to do that in postman?

Answer (score 0):

You can put below script in Postman test script section:

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();

const dataId = jsonData.items.find
      (m => m.title === "Number 2");

pm.globals.set("id", dataId.id);
```